# What does it actually mean by World, Window and Viewport?

Tags: coordinates

I am studying Computer Graphics myself. I am stuck with the concept of World, Window and View-port.

As far as I understood:

(1) **World** - is an abstract and imaginary space that is imagined to exist inside the Graphics rendering software (like [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)), [3D Studio Max](https://www.google.pl/search?q=3d%20studio%20max&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=603&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_0ihVYnID4jlywOAzKrIDw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ), and so on) or a framework/library/engine like [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) or [Directx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), or, [Unreal Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine) where the objects/models (to be displayed) are measured in units specific to that software or library or engine. We are generally habituated to measure pictures of all geometric objects as the units of integer/real numbers on papers or books. And, in computer monitor screens they are measured in Pixels. But, due to some problems like ________________, developers use a coordinate system imagined and implemented in their software/framework/library/ engine and that is called a World Coordinate system. For example, OpenGL uses fractional values to measure and plot an object which seems to be totally impossible, because, computer screens do not have such abilities, they only understand pixels. So what is the catch? Before displaying on the computer screen, the OpenGL's world coordinate measurements are converted to actual screen pixels (through a mechanism called [Graphics Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline)) and that is how a model or object can be displayed on the computer screen.

(2) **Window** - Window is the a cut-section area (that we want to display on the computer screen) of the imaginary graphics World.

(3) **Viewport** - Viewport is the actual image we see on the screen. That is displayed by converting the world coordinate into screen pixels.

Am I correct?

Please, fill in the blank and review my conception thus far.

---

**And, if you do down-vote, or, closed-vote, please, leave a comment so that I can understand the reason.**

Comment: The world coordinates are the ones where you model your simulated objects. You can use meters if this makes sense to your needs. I'd model everything as a "real world" size, in meters, for instance. There is nothing to fill the blank. You could use _meters_, _feet_, _kilometres_, _miles_, _baby steps_, _AU_, or invent an _askkekdksl_ length standard. This really depends on the implementation of what you're simulating, and could depend on the context. The view and projection matrices take care to transform the world items to screen coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the real world. We have all kinds of things measured in meters and feet. Now how many, say, meters across is your field of view? Clearly, you need to know more about that question to continue. At what distance? Horizontally? Vertically? Even the arrangement of cells on your retina doesn't indicate how much of the world you can see.

The same problem exists in projection. We have some 3D surfaces in an imaginary world (the unit of its coordinates is just a matter of interpretation - we use different units depending on the scale we're simulating), and we want to project them onto a 2D surface that we will then display on the monitor.

So, we define a 3D surface with some particular size in the world on which to project things onto (in practice the surface is only implied by the matrix) and then scale and translate the 3D vertices so they lie in line with that surface. Imagine drawing a line from every vertex through the surface to some point, then moving them to the point where the intersect with the surface. That is the duty of the projection matrix.

Now that all the 3D stuff is 2D, we just have to scale the surface to the pixel resolution and map the textures' coordinates onto it.

This is a very simplified view, since there's a lot of tweaks like [filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering) and [z-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) that usually need to happen in between, but that's the problem and a short explanation of the solution.

Comment: are my conceptions about Window and Viewport correct?

Answer (score 0):

While trying to understand the subject I found [this great book](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter04.html). It's a dense and complete cheat sheet for all spaces you will possibly deal in 3D. Answering your question:

1. "The purpose of world space is to provide some absolute reference for all the objects in your scene."
2. No, `Window` is usually a synonym to `Viewport`. Possibly that you talking about is a clip space.
3. That is somewhat correct, "converting the world coordinate into screen pixels" doesn't sound particularly right because there is no direct transformation, unless you have at least a view point.

Answer (score 0):

I think my basic idea will be helpful here: i found from different material during my study.

A rectangular area specified in world coordinates is called a window.
A rectangular area on the display device to which a window is mapped is called a view port.
The window defines what is to be viewed; the view port defines where it is to be displayed.
Often windows and view ports are rectangles in standard position with rectangle edges parallel to coordinate axes
 The mapping of a part of world coordinate scene to device coordinate is referred to as viewing transformation.   hope this is useful.